# Converting sympy function to lambda function

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

I've been trying to convert my sympy function variable which looks like this:-

(atan(−3/)+2.66602685430536⋅10−6)^2+(atan(−2/)−0.0896686524911619)^2+(atan(−1/)−0.16739555984988)^2

[Function expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkLDU.png)

I've been trying to use lambdastr and lambdify for this purpose. In the following way:-

```
s = lambdastr((x,z),function)
lam_func = lambdify([x,z],s,myfuncs)
```

But keep getting this error:-

***AttributeError***: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'atan'

I figured out it was because the lambdastr adds math module for the atan function in the following way:-

```
s = lambdastr((x,z),function)
print(s)
```

> lambda x,z: ((**math.atan**((z - 3)/x) + 2.66602685430536e-6)**2 +
>   (**math.atan**((z - 2)/x) - 0.0896686524911619)**2 + (**math.atan**((z - 1)/x)
>   - 0.16739555984988)**2)

So, I implemented the atan separately like this:-

```
s = lambdastr((x,z),function)
s = s.replace("math.atan","tan_inv")
def tan_inv_impl(x):
    return math.atan(x)
myfuncs = {"tan_inv":tan_inv_impl}
lam_func = lambdify([x,z],s,myfuncs)
```

This does give me a lambda function but it doesn't seem to work

```
lam_func(1,1)
```

Gives an error:

in _lambdifygenerated(x, z)

> 1 def _lambdifygenerated(x, z):
>   ----> 2     return (Lambda((x, z),
>   (tan_inv((z - 3)/x) + 2.66602685430536e-6)**2 + (tan_inv((z - 2)/x) -
>   0.0896686524911619)**2 + (tan_inv((z - 1)/x) - 0.16739555984988)**2))

**NameError**: name 'Lambda' is not defined

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Lambda`?

```
>>> from sympy import Lambda
>>> function  # defined as you described
(atan(z - 3/x) + 2.66602685430536e-6)**2 + (atan(z - 2/x) -           
0.0896686524911619)**2 + (atan(z - 1/x) - 0.16739555984988)**2
>>> f = Lambda((x,z), function)
>>> f(1,1).n()
2.01953558567067
```